# Flash Builder 4 automate building for Flash CS5?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Does Flash Builder 4 allow one to automate building Flash CS5/as3 .flas?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your meaning of 'automate'. In Flash Builder 4 you can set an actionscript project to a type of 'Flash Professional Project' which will then prompt you to select your CS5 .fla file.

This will allow you to publish via the FLash IDE from within Flash builder and also to launch the Flash IDE 'test movie' from within flash builder as well.

Each time you save your project it will automatically publish a debug version of your swf as well.

Performing debugging via Flash Builder on a project like this is possible but complicated. I've got it working but I'm currently looking for a more elegant solution.

b